# add cclayer on top of another

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cclayer

I want to add one cclayer on top of another. 
I have tried this by using following code

```
+(id) scene
{
CCScene *scene = [CCScene node];

GameScreen *layer = [GameScreen node];
[scene addChild: layer];

GameScreen *newLayer=[GameScreen node];
[scene addChild:newLayer];

return scene;
}
```

but may be there are some mistakes, cuz when i tried to add something on newLayer ,it says using undeclared variable even when ideclared that in .h file also.

Can you please help me with detail code?

Comment: what is the exact error you got? able to show the .h as well?

Comment: newLayer es only defined on the scene method, so if you want to use outside that method you get the error...

Comment: I want to add text on newLayer(2nd) and add sprites on layer(1st one). So it should look on same scene. And,i want to apply touch to only newLayer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of doing this in the "scene" class method, add the "new" CCLayer in the -(id)init{} method:

```
-(id) init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        GameScreen *newLayer=[GameScreen node];
        [self addChild:newLayer];

         //Other code        

    } return self;
}
```

Comment: Tried that too.But then,it won't go below that code([self addChild:newLayer];). It continuosly calls the code before adding new layer and after some time crashes.

Comment: Or tell me, can we add two layers in same scene and how?

Comment: thats real strange...usually you can add as many CCLayers as you please...do you mind sharing more of the code?